# DataFrame non-NaN series assignment results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot find a reason why when I assign *scaled* variable (which is non NaN) to the original DataFrame I get NaNs even though the index matches (years).

Can anyone help? I am leaving out details which I think are not necessary, happy to provide more details if needed.

[image]

Comment: please share the data in a way the issue can be reproduced (small sample of data) and not in print screens

Comment: apologies, my thinking was that this will be obvious to someone who knows why this happens without the need to reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given the following multi-index dataframe `df`:

```py
                     value
country        year       
Canada         2007      1
               2006      2
               2005      3
United Kingdom 2007      4
               2006      5
```

And the following series `scaled`:

```py
2006    99
2007    54
2005    78
dtype: int64
```

You can assign it as a new column if [reindexed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and converted [to a list](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) first, like this:

```py
df.loc["Canada", "new_values"] = scaled.reindex(df.loc["Canada", :].index).to_list()

print(df.loc["Canada", :])

# Output
      value  new_values
year
2007      1        54.0
2006      2        99.0
2005      3        78.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I think it relies on the fact that the items are in the same order right? I did it as series assignment to make sure the indexes would be matched (i.e. the order would not matter). Any idea why series assignment doesn't work please?

Comment: Indeed, see my updated answer.